# Prevent user liking own comments in Django API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm hopeful someone can help with this problem. I believe the answer is probably straightfoward but it's eluding me. I'm creating a messaging API where users like comments, however, I want to prevent a user from liking their own comment

I have the following Like model linking to a Message model:

```
# models.py

class Like(models.Model):
    message_id = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name='message_id_like', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like = models.BooleanField()
    like_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.owner) + ', ' + self.message_id.message_title[:40]
```

With a serializer for the API

```
# serializers.py

class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = [
            'message_id',
            'owner',
            'like',
            'like_date',
            ]
```

And a view:

```
# views.py

class LikeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): 
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer): # Saving the user
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

I believe I need an additional function within the LikeViewSet class that prevents the creation of a like when Like user matches Message user, however, I do not know how to specify it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this using a variation of submitted answers. The secret sauce to avoid the serializer access error was the initial_data method (rather than the validated_data method which pulls back the wrong data).

```
def perform_create(self, serializer): 
    message = get_object_or_404(Message, pk=serializer.initial_data['message_id'])
    if message.owner == self.request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this. But preventing means a lot. Whether to show some error or silently prevent.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer): # Saving the user
    if serializer.data['message_id'].user == self.request.user:
        # error handle for self like
    else:
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I think it's returning an object in the id field - I get this error: "Field 'id' expected a number but got <Message: Test message>". I've played with the code a few ways but can't resolve. I also had to change the method to validated_data as I recieved an error saying I couldn't save it otherwise. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok. Then you can directly compare. Updated

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Django Rest Framework, the most elegant way is to write a custom [Permission Class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/). It could look like this:

```
class IsNotOwnerCanLike(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action == "create":
            return not request.data["message_id"].user == request.user
```

and then in your ViewSet you should specify

```
permission_classes = [IsNotOwnerCanLike]
```

This way, when the owner tries to like their own post, they will get a HTTP 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need to specify `like` field and `like_date` could be named just `created_at`